# react router code in separate file

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to reactjs and working to learn redux with react router. I want to have routes as separate file. However somehow its not working because I am not able to pass the dependencies. Following is code details.

Working index.js having routes as well:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {ReduxRouter} from "redux-react-router";
import {Route} from "react-router"

import createBrowserHistory from "history/lib/createBrowserHistory"
import configureStore from './store';

import App from "./containers/App";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Countries from "./components/Countries";
import {fetchData} from './actions/actions';

const history = new createBrowserHistory();
const store = configureStore();

function loadData() {
  store.dispatch(fetchData('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all'))
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReduxRouter>
      <Route history={history}>
        <Route component={App}>
          <Route path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/countries' component={Countries} onEnter={loadData} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </ReduxRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Following is the code which I tried to split as separate routes.js

index.js

```
import 'babel-core/polyfill';
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {ReduxRouter} from "redux-react-router";
import {Route} from "react-router"

import createBrowserHistory from "history/lib/createBrowserHistory"
import configureStore from './store';

import routes from "./routes";
import {fetchData} from './actions/actions';

const history = new createBrowserHistory();
const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReduxRouter>
      <Route history={history} routes={routes}>        
      </Route>
    </ReduxRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

routes.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {ReduxRouter} from "redux-react-router";
import {Route} from "react-router"


import App from "./../containers/App";
import Home from "./../components/Home";
import Countries from "./../components/Countries";

const router =
<Route history={history}>
  <Route component={App}>
    <Route path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route path='/countries' component={Countries} onEnter={loadData} />
  </Route>
</Route>;

export default router;
```

However it is throwing error as not able to identify loadData function.

Please help.

Comment: Why do not you move loadData method (and its dependencies as well like store, configureStore, fetchData) to routes.js?

Comment: bcz "store" is also part of top <Provider> as  <Provider store={store}>

Comment: Then you can have store in both index.js and routes.js

Comment: I can't. I should create store object only once.

Comment: Can you add your store.js?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pass it as a child, note the parent is called `Router`:

```
<Router history={history}>
  {routes}        
</Router>
```

Also `Route` doesn't take the history prop, `Router` does.

See an example of Router.js and Route.js on a starter of mine: https://github.com/DominicTobias/universal-react/tree/master/app

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, it helped me to solve this problem. I am sharing my changed code in this post as well.

Comment: Got a question, `export default (<.. />)` is this exporting a default function? Or const?

Answer (score 3):

After following the answer given by Dominic I changed my code as below to pass the dependency as function argument as I don't want to create the store object again. Now its working fine. Following is modified code.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {ReduxRouter} from "redux-react-router";
import {Route} from "react-router"

import createBrowserHistory from "history/lib/createBrowserHistory"
import configureStore from './store';

import App from "./containers/App";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Countries from "./components/Countries";
import {fetchData} from './actions/actions';
import routes from "./routes";

const history = new createBrowserHistory();
const store = configureStore();

function loadData() {
  store.dispatch(fetchData('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all'))
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReduxRouter>
      <Route history={history}>
        {routes(loadData)}
      </Route>
    </ReduxRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

routes.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {ReduxRouter} from "redux-react-router";
import {Route} from "react-router"


import App from "./../containers/App";
import Home from "./../components/Home";
import Countries from "./../components/Countries";

function router(loadData) {
  return (<Route component={App}>
          <Route path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/countries' component={Countries} onEnter={loadData} />
        </Route>);
}
export default router;
```